# Derby Sequence Loop in junit test

Tags: hibernate, loops, sequence, derby

I'm in trouble when using Derby with embedded driver (derby-10.9.1.0) and in-memory db in my JUNIT with Hibernate (hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final) environment.

I'm using annotations and using hbm2ddl to create my in-memory db.

Everything is working except when I try to use an sequence.

The sequence is created (it appears in the log), but when I try to add one entity (hibernate) with PK related to that sequence my code starts a infinite loop writing in each line:

```
Hibernate: values next value for app.SE_FERI
```

My db is created as:

```
jdbc:derby:memory:testdb;create=true
```

I'm using hbm2ddl inside my code, before the database use, as:

```
SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(config);
schemaExport.drop(true, true);
schemaExport.create(true, true);
```

Some help !?

Comment: I had the same problem. I switched to [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org/) and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurres when the allocationSize of the sequence is set to 1. Setting it to a value > 1 worked for me.

I know this thread is kinda old, but if anybody else has this problem, this could be the solution.

Edit: spelling

Comment: thank you very much!! scarce information around this topic! Anyway, initial-value="1" still not working, as it starts from the biggest negative number, that's weird.

Comment: I can only confirm the bug is Derby specific, allocationSize 1 works with HSQLDB or H2 (using hibernate).